# How to check if my NPC sees the back of a target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I think the title says it all. Can it be done using only vector math?

```
var toTarget = (enemy.transform.position - npc.transform.position).normalized;
var seesBack = Vector3.Dot(toTarget, npc.transform.forward) < 0;
```

It seems I should somehow mix target's forward vector into the equation, but I'm really lame when it comes to vector math (well, math in general ;) ). Anyone?

EDIT:

I've also tried doing this, but the angle is too low. For example if the NPC is on the right of it's target, the calculated angle is ~60 degrees:

```
var angle = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Angle(enemy.transform.forward * -1, npc.transform.forward));
var seesBack = angle <= 70;
```

Comment: In a nutshell, yes, you can only do it using vector math.  Potentially you could add front-face and back-face triggers but then you'd be using a raycast which is still using vector math, you just don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close!  Consider that for the npc to see the back of the enemy, the enemy has to be looking roughly in the same direction as the vector from the npc to the enemy, aka `toTarget`:

```
var toTarget = (enemy.transform.position - npc.transform.position).normalized;
var seesBack = Vector3.Dot(toTarget, enemy.transform.forward) > 0;
```

Note that the Dot is against the enemy transform, and greater than 0.

Comment: Your original `seesBack` test only checked if the npc could see the enemy at all.  You may still need that. =)

Comment: Oh this is really clever.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these tell you the same thing:

Are the two *facing in the same direction?*

Neither one tell you anything about which one is *in front.*

The dot-product one is going to be better, but you need to also check who's behind whom.

The one off-the-top-of-my-head way that I can think of is to compare the distance between the two entities, add a small amount along the NPC's forward vector (like, 0.5 units, something half the size of its collision volume's thickness) and get the distance from that point to the center of the other entity.

If the offset distance is smaller, the NPC is behind (as by moving forward, it would get closer). You'll probably also want a distance check involved somewhere as well, so that "behind" doesn't include "three rooms over." But I assume you've done that already.

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be done using only vector math?

This will check if the enemy is both facing away *and* positioned in-front of the NPC.

```
var r = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, enemy.transform.forward) > 0f &&
        Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, enemy.transform.position - transform.position) > 0f;
```

Comment: Some people on SO are just... Well - annoying to say the least. Downvoting is only ok, if you give a good reason and your answer also works I think, so the person putting a downvote on it should at least say why.